# Snowflake transactions and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to have one transaction for all queries coming out of Spark? From what I can tell, transactions are not supported. However, recently I had came across the following piece of code in our Spark (pyspark) jobs that is trying to use snowflake transactions:

```
    run_snowflake_query(sfOptions, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;")
    run_snowflake_query(sfOptions, prep_query_1)
    run_snowflake_query(sfOptions, prep_query_2)
    df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option(
        "dbtable", OUTPUT_TABLE
    ).mode("append").save()   
    run_snowflake_query(sfOptions, delete_query_1)
    run_snowflake_query(sfOptions, "COMMIT;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports transactions:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html

When using transactions through a connector you need to be careful with concurrency:

> Although multiple sessions cannot share the same transaction, multiple threads using a single connection share the same session, and thus share the same transaction. This can lead to unexpected results, such as one thread rolling back work done in another thread.

> This situation can occur when a client application using a Snowflake driver (such as the Snowflake JDBC Driver) or connector (such as the Snowflake Connector for Python) is multi-threaded. If two or more threads share the same connection, then those threads also share the current transaction in that connection. A BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT, or ROLLBACK by one thread affects all threads using that shared connection. If the threads are running asynchronously, the results can be unpredictable.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#label-transactions-and-multi-threading

You also need to be aware that DDL statements (like `CREATE TABLE`) occur in their own transactions:

> If a DDL statement is executed while a transaction is active, the DDL statement:
> Implicitly commits the active transaction.
> Executes the DDL statement as a separate transaction.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#ddl

Comment: Thanks. I am able to use the transactions with sqlalchemy and with Airflow. However, Spark is a distributed system, and I am not quite sure that transactions would work with spark data writer. As far as I can tell ```net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery``` creates a new connection each time, so, in theory transactions will not work.